# Large Meteor applications taking too much time for initial loading

Tags: meteor, bundle

I am working on Meteor app(e-commerce site), became very large. It almost takes 9secs to view static part of homepage till then it only shows white/blank screen. After that it starts showing data from  DB(mongoDB). The whole site with data takes ~24secs to come at client side. I think the whole bundle is too much huge and that is why it takes more time to download. And it is causing 9secs of white screen. Any solution guys. Thanks in advance!

```
Alraedy Tried:
1. Fast Render(Flowrouter subscriptions) package
2. Appcache package
3. Query Optimization/Indexing
4. Removed global subscriptions
5. Sending minimal data via pub/sub
6. this.unblock() for publications
7. Not saving files in DB instead saving url's
```

Comment: there's no way any of us can actually help you as it could be a number of things. you need to profile your database, your server, and dig into the dev tools of your browser. e.g. how fast is your server? how fast is your db? are they in the same co-loco? is it your code? too much data? are your expectations reasonable? it's impossible to tell just based on how long it takes you to see the page.

Comment: Using the chrome dev tools you should be able to determine the payload size of your first page load. How big is that? How long until your first subscriptions start receiving data? (You can detect that by looking for websocket connections).

Answer (score 1):

You are working on an e-commerce website and so you might have a huge admin module bundled with your website. You should consider building the admin module as a separate Meteor app sharing the same Mongo DB collections with the e-commerce website. You can reduce the size of you app considerably using this approach. You can find more details [here](http://devepics.com/meteor-microservices-building-an-admin-panel-as-a-seperate-meteor-js-app/)

You should also be really careful about your subscriptions and use pagination on the server side publications, subscribing to only what data is actually required

Comment: Yes. Admin side is very huge, which includes all the reports and admin controls. We were thinking about shifting admin part but thought may be there are some others solutions. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, try to remove unused packages which aren't used anymore by any frontend code. Check your entire package.json and all imports.

Reduce the size of all you subscriptions, you probably have tons of them with entire or too big documents, which is easy while developing, but an overkill in production. Try to limit the fields and the amount of loaded objects to what you visualise for the user.

Don't wait for all subscriptions to finsih loading before showing something, load the website and it's design already, but only show a 'loading' icon on the parts that do require data to be shown dynamically.

Make sure your javascript is minified before it's published, this saves a lot of bandwidth.

After implementing these your load times should have decreased.

Providing a detailed network analytic from the debugger of your browser might also help to notcie problems.

Comment: `After implementing these your load times should have increased.` -- I hope you meant decreased :)

Comment: yeah, changing that now.

Comment: Meteor should minify js automatically in production.

Comment: Only if set to production, it might be something overlooked by some.